# Как поменять значение innerHTML у блоков, находящихся в одном блоке-родителе?

Tags: javascript

Есть div-родитель, в котором лежит большое количество дочерних div'ов. При помощи данной конструкции, я получаю номер дочернего div'а, по которому был произведен клик:

```
document.querySelector('#main').addEventListener("click", function(evt){
  log = [].indexOf.call(this.children, evt.target);
});
```

Далее при помощи evt.target я могу изменить содержимое div'a, по которому я произвел клик:

```
evt.target.innerHTML = "lorem ipsum";
```

Допустим, что в переменную log я записал число 32 (что соответствует 32-му div'у в блоке-родителе), но теперь я хочу изменить свойство innerHTML, у соседнего div'a, например, под номером 33(ну или вообще 1 или 44). Могу ли я с помощью номера div'a получить какое-нибудь подобие event.target'а, чтобы я мог поменять в нем значение innerHTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное как-то так:

Я тут сделал массив из потомков и взял элемент по индексу + 2

```
let log_2 = [].slice.call(this.children)[log+2];
```

однако такой подход  таит в себе грабли. лучше использовать идентификаторы

```html
<div id="main">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>

<script>
    document.querySelector('#main').addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    
      let log = [].indexOf.call(this.children, evt.target);
      let log_2 = [].slice.call(this.children)[log+2];
      
      evt.target.innerText = "target";
      log_2.innerText = "target + 2";
      
    });
</script>
```